How to execute scripts from a samba drive (cifs mounted)?
If I'm starting a shell script "test.sh" from a samba share, I've got an error:
bash: ./test.sh: /bin/sh: Defekter Interpreter: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler

(bash: ./test.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: input/output error)
The script is not executed.
My script:
#!/bin/sh
echo "test"

If I'm doing the same on a local drive, there's no problem, it executes fine.
The share is mounted in fstab:
//192.168.1.15/Netdrive  /home/measuser/Netdrive  cifs  noauto,rw,exec,users,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/measuser/.config/.smb-cred  0 0

If I'm using "/bin/sh ./test.sh" or "/bin/sh /home/measuser/Netdrive/test.sh" on the network drive, everything works fine.
What do I have to do, to fix this problem?
My system:
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-26-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700K
Memory: 62.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2


IIRC: the user mount option turns off exec by default. So drop users "everything works fine."  that's cuz sh and bash are on an ext partition. You are parsing the script not executing it, Bash/sh executes it

Both the user and users option are position dependent according to man mount: "This option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line users,exec,dev,suid)." (although I'd have expected the error to be Permission denied rather than bad interpreter: input/output error - perhaps that's due to CIFS?). See also My SSD Partitions are mounting as noexec, in defiance of fstab .

Thanks. Without users, the share will not mount. I've changed fstab for: //192.168.1.15/Netdrive  /home/measuser/Netdrive  cifs  noauto,users,rw,exec,credentials=/home/measuser/.config/.smb-cred  0 0. So exec comes after users, but the problem still consists.

I think this bug is related to the issue. Bug in kernel 6.5:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.5/+bug/2052835

I was able to execute .sh scripts from cifs share by calling
sh /path/test.sh

instead of
/path/test.sh


It's been my observation that windows (XP at lease) has something called the archive bit which is on when a file is modified.  It can be turned off and some backup programs sweep through turning off these archive bits as they make backup copies (think Nero CD burning software).
That archive bit appears, at least in my environment, to be the same bit presented as the execute bit in the ubuntu environment.
Think DOS attrib command for toggling this bit on a real Windows (XP) system.

Thanks. My shares are on a QNAP NAS. The files are all marked as executable.

This has nothing to do with Windows XP. It is obviously a bug. CIFS seems not properly tested in new kernels. With an older kernel I didn't have this problem. There are other problems too since Kernel Version: 6.5.0-27-lowlatency, there it is no more possible, to copy a file from a smb share to a location on the same share. The things are getting more and more weird.

What about the mainline kernels? Are this problems there too? Can I upgrade Ubuntu Studio with a mainline kernel, as example 6.8.8 ?
